# Saving CSS class on object in localstorage on reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, local-storage

What I would like to do, is to have a CSS style saved when a user resreshes the page. This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

$("#slider").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > 230) {
            $("#well").fadeOut();
            $( "#well" ).addClass( "disappear" );
        } else {
            // Apparently Safari isn't allowing partial opacity on text with background clip? Not sure.
            // $("h2 span").css("opacity", 100 - (ui.position.left / 5))
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 231) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })
        }
    }
});

$('#slider')[0].addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var el = event.target;
    var touch = event.touches[0];
    curX = touch.pageX - this.offsetLeft - 73;
    if(curX <= 0) return;
    if(curX > 230){
        $('#well').fadeOut();
    }
    el.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(' + curX + 'px)'; 
}, false);

$('#slider')[0].addEventListener('touchend', function(event) {  
    this.style.webkitTransition = '-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in';
    this.addEventListener( 'webkitTransitionEnd', function( event ) { this.style.webkitTransition = 'none'; }, false );
    this.style.webkitTransform = 'translateX(0px)';
}, false);
```

});

When the class "disappear" is added I would like to keep it added even if the page reloads. I found a useful post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage), but since I am a beginner at Javascript, I am not sure how to use it in my case, and I would be really happy if someone could give me a personalized answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$( "#well" ).addClass( "disappear" );` add

```
localStorage['wellClass'] = 'disappear';
```

And in the line below `$(function() {` add

```
previousWellClass = localStorage['wellClass'];
if (previousWellClass) $('#well').addClass(previousWellClass);
```

Comment: Great, this did the trick with very little work! However, it does not seem to work on iPhone... Any thoughs on that?

Answer (score 0):

This will do most of the work for you.

```
var setClass = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('setClass')) || {};
$.each(setClass, function () {
    $(this.selector).addClass(this.className);
});
var addClassToLocalStorage = function(selector, className) {
    setClass[selector + ':' + className] = {
        selector: selector,
        className: className
    };
    localStorage.setItem('setClass', JSON.stringify(setClass));
};
var removeClassFromLocalStorage = function(selector, className) {
    delete setClass[selector + ':' + className];
    localStorage.setItem('setClass', JSON.stringify(setClass));
};
```

Then you can just do this:

```
$("#well").fadeOut();
$("#well").addClass("disappear");
addClassToLocalStorage('#well', 'disappear');
// remove it removeClassFromLocalStorage('#well', 'disappear');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ukJGB/4/)**

Then you can reuse it if you need to later.