# Set multiple scrollbar positions on EndRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ASP.NET page that posts back every so often, so I looked around for a solution to maintain the scrollbar positions of scrollable divs on the page. I found a solution that worked for a single div (the first one jquery finds with `$get`), but I'm trying to rework it to go through each one.

```
 var xPos = [];
 var yPos = [];
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
 prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     yPos = [];
     xPos = [];
     $('tableContainer').each(function (theIndex, element) {
         xPos[theIndex] = $(this).scrollLeft;
         yPos[theIndex] = $(this).scrollTop;

     });

 }

 function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     $('tableContainer').each(function (theIndex, element) {
         $(this).scrollLeft = xPos[theIndex];
         $(this).scrollTop = yPos[theIndex];

     });

 }
```

Here's where I've gotten so far, but this doesn't seem to do the trick and I'm not sure where it's hanging up. I put it in jsfiddle to make sure there were no syntax errors I was missing, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Can someone offer a little insight? It seems to run for a while and then eventually throw an index out of bounds error; I would think resetting the arrays at the beginning of the request handler would prevent that, at least.

Comment: Have you thought about localStorage? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830004/use-html5-localstorage-to-retain-jquery-toggle-state-on-page-refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, this is how I ended up resolving the issue. I realized that the elements I was using all had the same ID, so instead I iterate through the class.

```
 var xPos = [4];
 var yPos = [4];
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
 prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {

     $(".tableContainer").each(function (theIndex, element) {
         xPos[theIndex] = $(this).scrollLeft;
         yPos[theIndex] = $(this).scrollTop;

     });

 }

 function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     $(".tableContainer").each(function (theIndex, element) {
         $(this).scrollLeft = xPos[theIndex];
         $(this).scrollTop = yPos[theIndex];
      });


 }
```