# How to make Sub Menu still appear after redirect to new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im making a simple website.

My menubar is located on MasterPage. So that every other page using the master page the menubar is still intact.

The submenu of the menubar is expanding if you click the main menu link.

Here is the codepen of my menubar : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRzXNg

Here is my MenuBar html code :

```css
    nav {
      /*
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 50%;
      right: 0;
        */
    }

    ul.menu {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      padding: auto;
      background-color: #DCE6F2;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    }

    ul.menu li {
      float: left;
      width: auto;
    }

    ul.menu li a {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.menu li a:focus {
      background-color: #DCE6F2;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: underline;
      -moz-transition-property: background-color;
      -o-transition-property: background-color;
      -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
      transition-property: background-color;
      -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    }

    ul.menu li a:focus+ul,
    ul.menu li a+ul:hover {
      width: 100%;
      background: #95B3D7;
      visibility: visible;
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
      opacity: 1;
      -moz-transition-property: opacity;
      -o-transition-property: opacity;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
      transition-property: opacity;
      -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
      transition-duration: 0.33s;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }

    ul.sub-menu {
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
      background-color: #95B3D7;
    }

    ul.sub-menu li:hover {
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }

    ul.menu a,
    ul.sub-menu a {
      font-family: Calibri, Arial;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #0E0500;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="home.aspx">Beranda</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Tabel</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="MasterNPWP.aspx">NPWP</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterCabang.aspx">Branch</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterDivision.aspx">Division</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterDepartemen.aspx">Department</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterSubDepartemen.aspx">Sub Department</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterGroup.aspx">Group</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterGrade.aspx">Grade</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterPosition.aspx">Position</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterBank.aspx">Bank</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterCountry.aspx">Country</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterEducation.aspx">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterActualMaritalStatus.aspx">Actual Marital Status</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterWorkingPerformance.aspx">Working Performance</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Pegawai</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="MasterPegawai.aspx">Data Induk Pegawai</a></li>
          <li><a href="LaporanPegawai.aspx">Laporan Pegawai</a></li>
          <li><a href="MasterSlipGaji.aspx">Slip Gaji</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Pajak</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Parameter Pajak</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kalkulator Pajak</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Perhitungan Manual</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Sistem</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="MasterUser.aspx">Pengguna</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Perusahaan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="LogOut.aspx">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Im using a:focus to expand the submenu.

Now after I click the link on submenu. It is of course redirect to another page which is using the same MasterPage. But the sub menu is disappear on the new page.

How to make the sub menu is still expanding even after response redirect ? Im using MasterPage FYI.

Comment: only if create class for like `ul.visible` with `visibility: visible; opacity: 1` and add it for active `ul` in another page

Comment: You can also store the state in localstorage or sessionstorage and get it back in the next page.

Comment: This isn't related to VB.NET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22830078/5396995 check this